# Capture stdout for a long time in bash

Tags: bash, unix

I'm using a script which is calling another, like this :

```
# stuff...
OUT="$(./scriptB)"
# do stuff with the variable OUT
```

Basically, the scriptB script displays text in multiple time. Ie : it displays a line, 2s late another, 3s later another and so on.

With the snippet i use, i only get the first output of my command, i miss a lot. 
How can i get the whole output, by capturing stdout for a given time ? Something like :

```
begin capture
./scriptB
stop capture
```

I don't mind if the output is not shown on screen.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to store the all outputs given by `./scriptB` Am I right?

Comment: your `OUT=$(./scriptB)` should work as you expect (you don't need the dbl-quotes). It seems like there must be something in `./scriptB` that's not working as you expect. Can you prove your case with a very simplified version of `./scriptB`. Maybe `while true ; do echo $((++i); sleep 1 ; done`. Also, your question has a lot of ambigutity:  "how can I tell the whole output" is different (to me) than "capturing stdout for a given time". Please clarify with sample data! ;-) Good luck.

Comment: @Karthikeyan.R.S Yep, every single byte.

Comment: @shellter I'm gonna edit my question

Comment: Sounds like lines 2 and 3 might be printed by a different process. The construct you have will capture all the output from the process you start, and wait for it to finish. In other words, what @shellter said.

Comment: Yep, i investigate and it seems like i get some output from another process. How can i get theses ?

Comment: hm... try `{ ./scriptB ; } > /tmp/scriptB.log 2>&1`. If that doesn't work, then we need more details about what is happening inside `./scriptB`. Good luck (and good night ;-) )

Comment: YES ! @shellter this is it ! Post an answer and i'll accept it. Thanks you ;)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, then I believe you can use the [`tee` command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_%28command%29), like

```
./scriptB | tee $HOME/scriptB.log
```

It will display the stdout from `scriptB` and write stdout to the log file at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Some of your output seems to be coming on the STDERR stream. So we have to redirect that as needed. As in my comment, you can do

```
{ ./scriptB ; } > /tmp/scriptB.log 2>&1
```

Which can almost certainly be reduced to

```
./scriptB  > /tmp/scriptB.log 2>&1
```

And in newer versions of bash, can further be reduced to

```
 ./scriptB >& /tmp/scriptB.log
```

AND finally, as your original question involved storing the output to a variable, you can do

```
 OUT=$(./scriptB > /tmp/scriptB.log 2>&1)
```

The notation `2>&1` says, take the file descriptor 2 of this process (STDERR) and tie it (`&`) into the  file descriptor 1 of the process (STDOUT).

The alternate notation provided ( `... >& file`) is a shorthand for the `2>&1`.

Personally, I'd recommend using the `2>&1` syntax, as this is understood by all Bourne derived shells (not [t]csh).

As an aside, all processes by default have 3 file descriptors created when the process is created, 0=STDIN, 1=STDOUT, 2=STDERR. Manipulation of those streams is usually as simple as illustrated here. More advanced (rare) manipulations are possible. Post a separate question if you need to know more.

IHTH